# Gmail - Ways to have more than 20 items per page in the search results

Tags: google-chrome, search, gmail, google-chrome-extensions

Gmail has the notorious limitation of 20 results per page when searching your mail.

Is there an extension (Chrome - preferable, Firefox, etc.) that can fix this (i.e. allow more than 20 items per page)?

Based on my experience this should be entirely doable (have the extension move across pages in the background and then collect the results). Is there an extension that can already do this? I'm asking because I couldn't find one.

Comment: Interestingly, this is not controlled by *Gmail's Setting* **Show `XX` conversations per page**... I think that's the place where it should be set.

Comment: It's 'kind of' controlled there...  see joereddington.com/2300/2014/02/08/better-gmail-search/ for the details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found such an extension or add-on myself, but you can use a small workaround to achieve the desired result. If I want more than 20 results, I do the following:

1. Labels > Manage Labels > Add a new label (lets name it "search")
2. Search for the desired search string
3. Mark all > Click "Select all conversations that match this search" on top of the search results
4. Labels > Click "search" or whatever you called the label and click apply
5. All search results are now labels "search" > Click the label "search" on the left side and the whole search result is returned, no 20 mail limit any more
6. When you are done, you should remove the label if you do not need the same search result again

Seems like a long list but after you have done this a few times you can do it in less than 15 seconds.

Comment: That's nice. If anyone wants to write an extension for this, this is a much easier way to do it. All your steps could be easily automated by such an extension.

Answer (score 1):

[Using  CrystalFire's excellent suggestion on Webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/56999/10707) - I made a bookmarklet, which you can get [here](http://joereddington.com/2300/2014/02/08/better-gmail-search/).  It increases the number of search results by 100, so from:

[image]

to

[image]